# Memory efficient power set algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, recursion, powerset

Trying to calculate all the subsets ([power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)) of the 9-letter string 'ABCDEFGHI'.

Using standard recursive methods, my machine hits out of memory (1GB) error before completing. I have no more physical memory.

How can this be done better? Language is no issue and results sent to the standard output is fine as well - it does not need to be held all in memory before outputting.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Non-recursive_version

Comment: @tur1ng Ah, thats cool. I'll try compiling and see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got a mistake in your algorithm? Does it work for smaller inputs? The reason I ask is that there are 2^9 = 512 subsets of 'ABCDEFGHI' and getting 1GB of memory used means you *must* be doing something wrong...

Comment: @Rupert Swarbrick Yes, you could be right.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a trivial bijective mapping from the power set of X = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I} to the set of numbers between 0 and 2^|X| = 2^9:

Ø maps to 000000000 (base 2)

{A} maps to 100000000 (base 2)

{B} maps to 010000000 (base 2)

{C} maps to 001000000 (base 2)

...

{I} maps to 000000001 (base 2)

{A,B} maps to 110000000 (base 2)

{A,C} maps to 101000000 (base 2)

...

{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I} maps to 111111111 (base 2)

You can use this observation to create the power set like this (pseudo-code):

```
Set powerset = new Set();
for(int i between 0 and 2^9)
{
  Set subset = new Set();
  for each enabled bit in i add the corresponding letter to subset
  add subset to powerset
}
```

In this way you avoid any recursion (and, depending on what you need the powerset for, you may even be able to "generate" the powerset without allocating many data structures - for example, if you just need to print out the power set).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: you are a genius, so smart idea

Answer (score 1):

I would use divide and conquer for this:

```
Set powerSet(Set set) {
  return merge(powerSet(Set leftHalf), powerSet(Set rightHalf));
}

merge(Set leftHalf, Set rightHalf) {
  return union(leftHalf, rightHalf, allPairwiseCombinations(leftHalf, rightHalf));
}
```

That way, you immediately see that the number of solutions is 2^|originalSet| - that's why it is called the "power set". In your case, this would be 2^9, so there should not be an out of memory error on a 1GB machine. I guess you have some error in your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

a little scheme solution

```
(define (power_set_iter set)
  (let loop ((res '(())) 
             (s    set ))
    (if (empty? s)
        res
        (loop (append (map (lambda (i) 
                             (cons (car s) i)) 
                           res) 
                      res) 
              (cdr s)))))
```

Or in R5RS Scheme, more space efficient version

```
(define (pset s)
  (do ((r '(()))
       (s s (cdr s)))
      ((null? s) r)
    (for-each 
      (lambda (i) 
        (set! r (cons (cons (car s) i) 
                      r)))
      (reverse r))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I verified that this worked well:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_combination(char* str, char* buffer, int len, int num, int pos)
{
  if(num == 0)
  {
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  for(int i = pos; i < len - num + 1; ++i)
  {
    buffer[num - 1] = str[i];
    print_combination(str, buffer, len, num - 1, i + 1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "ABCDEFGHI";
  char buffer[10];
  for(auto i = 1u; i <= sizeof(str); ++i)
  {
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    print_combination(str, buffer, 9, i, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this elegant solution? Extend the code which generates nCr to iterate for r=1 till n!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int arr[],int s,int n)
{
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=s ; i<=n-1 ; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}

void combinateUtil(int arr[],int n,int i,int temp[],int r,int index)
{
    // What if n=5 and r=5, then we have to just print it and "return"!
    // Thus, have this base case first!
    if(index==r)
    {
        printArray(temp,0,r);
        return;
    }  

    // If i exceeds n, then there is no poin in recurring! Thus, return
    if(i>=n)
        return;


    temp[index]=arr[i];
    combinateUtil(arr,n,i+1,temp,r,index+1);
    combinateUtil(arr,n,i+1,temp,r,index);

}

void printCombinations(int arr[],int n)
{
    for(int r=1 ; r<=n ; r++)
    {
        int *temp = new int[r];
        combinateUtil(arr,n,0,temp,r,0);
    }
}



int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printCombinations(arr,n);

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The Output :

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
1 5 
2 3 
2 4 
2 5 
3 4 
3 5 
4 5 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 4 
1 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 3 4 
2 3 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 5 
1 2 4 5 
1 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: There's no empty set in the output.