# Generate a powerset with the help of a binary representation

Tags: binary, erlang, subset, powerset, gray-code

I know that "a powerset is simply any number between 0 and 2^N-1 where N is number of set members and one in binary presentation denotes presence of corresponding member".

([Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49197/hynek-pichi-vychodil))

I would like to generate a powerset using this mapping from the binary representation to the actual set elements.

How can I do this with Erlang?

I have tried to modify [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gray_code#Erlang), but with no success.

**UPD:** My goal is to write an iterative algorithm that generates a powerset of a set without keeping a stack. I tend to think that binary representation could help me with that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533336/generate-a-powerset-of-a-set-without-keeping-a-stack-in-erlang-or-ruby) is the successful solution in Ruby, but I need to write it in Erlang.

**UPD2:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371264/memory-efficient-power-set-algorithm) is the solution in pseudocode, I would like to make something similar in Erlang.

Comment: Question is somehow unclear. Powerset in set of all posible subsets of a given set. Gray code is a mapping from one number to another. What common between those two terms? And what you want to achieve? Can you provide some example?

Comment: I see. So you need two functions: one will produce numbers from 0 to 2^N-1, another for each number will do the following: for each (nth) bit of the number it will test if it is set. If bit is set, it must append corresponding (nth) element from original set to result set.

Comment: Yes, something like that, but unfortunately, I do not know how to make the second function, i.e. how to convert a decimal number into a binary representation; then map all 1's with corresponding subsets of set and add those subsets to the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would note that with Erlang a recursive solution does not necessarily imply it will consume extra stack.  When a method is tail-recursive (i.e., the last thing it does is the recursive call), the compiler will re-write it into modifying the parameters followed by a jump to the beginning of the method.  This is fairly standard for functional languages.

To generate a list of all the numbers A to B, use the library method [`lists:seq(A, B)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#seq-2).

To translate a list of values (such as the list from 0 to 2^N-1) into another list of values (such as the set generated from its binary representation), use [`lists:map`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#map-2) or a [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78732).

Instead of splitting a number into its binary representation, you might want to consider turning that around and checking whether the corresponding bit is set in each M value (in 0 to 2^N-1) by generating a list of power-of-2-bitmasks.  Then, you can do a binary AND to see if the bit is set.

Putting all of that together, you get a solution such as:

```
generate_powerset(List) ->
    % Do some pre-processing of the list to help with checks later.
    % This involves modifying the list to combine the element with
    % the bitmask it will need later on, such as:
    % [a, b, c, d, e] ==> [{1,a}, {2,b}, {4,c}, {8,d}, {16,e}]
    PowersOf2 = [1 bsl (X-1) || X <- lists:seq(1, length(List))],
    ListWithMasks = lists:zip(PowersOf2, List),

    % Generate the list from 0 to 1^N - 1
    AllMs = lists:seq(0, (1 bsl length(List)) - 1),

    % For each value, generate the corresponding subset
    lists:map(fun (M) -> generate_subset(M, ListWithMasks) end, AllMs).
    % or, using a list comprehension:
    % [generate_subset(M, ListWithMasks) || M <- AllMs].

generate_subset(M, ListWithMasks) ->
    % List comprehension: choose each element where the Mask value has
    % the corresponding bit set in M.
    [Element || {Mask, Element} <- ListWithMasks, M band Mask =/= 0].
```

However, you can also achieve the same thing using tail recursion without consuming stack space.  It also doesn't need to generate or keep around the list from 0 to 2^N-1.

```
generate_powerset(List) ->
    % same preliminary steps as above...
    PowersOf2 = [1 bsl (X-1) || X <- lists:seq(1, length(List))],
    ListWithMasks = lists:zip(PowersOf2, List),
    % call tail-recursive helper method -- it can have the same name
    % as long as it has different arity.
    generate_powerset(ListWithMasks, (1 bsl length(List)) - 1, []).

generate_powerset(_ListWithMasks, -1, Acc) -> Acc;
generate_powerset(ListWithMasks, M, Acc) ->
    generate_powerset(ListWithMasks, M-1,
                      [generate_subset(M, ListWithMasks) | Acc]).

% same as above...
generate_subset(M, ListWithMasks) ->
    [Element || {Mask, Element} <- ListWithMasks, M band Mask =/= 0].
```

Note that when generating the list of subsets, you'll want to put new elements at the head of the list.  Lists are singly-linked and immutable, so if you want to put an element anywhere but the beginning, it has to update the "next" pointers, which causes the list to be copied.  That's why the helper function puts the `Acc` list at the tail instead of doing `Acc ++ [generate_subset(...)]`.  In this case, since we're counting down instead of up, we're already going backwards, so it ends up coming out in the same order.

So, in conclusion,

1. Looping in Erlang is idiomatically done via a tail recursive function or using a variation of `lists:map`.
2. In many (most?) functional languages, including Erlang, tail recursion does not consume extra stack space since it is implemented using jumps.
3. List construction is typically done backwards (i.e., `[NewElement | ExistingList]`) for efficiency reasons.
4. You generally don't want to find the Nth item in a list (using [`lists:nth`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#nth-2)) since lists are singly-linked: it would have to iterate the list over and over again.  Instead, find a way to iterate the list once, such as how I pre-processed the bit masks above.

Comment: thank you! How can I modify this to be able to dump each subset to a file/ETC/anywhere? (my memory usage still keeps growing, I guess because of Acc accumulates all the results before the function returns)

Comment: Right.  It will keep it all in memory until the end.  If you use the tail recursive version, you can remove the Acc parameter completely and do the write to a file before the recursive step.  Such as: `generate_powerset(ListWithMasks, M) -> write_to_file(generate_subset(...)), generate_powerset(ListWithMasks, M-1).`